# ServiceStack does not show detailed message for 404

Tags: servicestack

```
public HttpResult GET(QueryMetadataRequest request)
{
    throw HttpError.NotFound("MY MESSAGE GOES HERE");
    //....
}
```

Throwing an excetion as above. and I don't see my message in the error page.

> Handler for Request not found:
>
> Request.HttpMethod: GET Request.PathInfo: /metadata/fefe/dsd
>   Request.QueryString:  Request.RawUrl: /metadata/fefe/dsd

How to let ServiceStack return detailed 404 error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should go in the HTTP Response Status Description, the page you're seeing is the default 404 `HttpHandler` built into ServiceStack for HTML page requests (e.g. from a Browser). If called from a data format, e.g:

```
/metadata/fefe/dsd.json
/metadata/fefe/dsd?format=json
```

You should see the structured error response as returned to ajax clients.

When not in [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode) the 404 page emits limited information by design. I've just [added a commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d60b977d755b002cea7e29adaf3cbb20e09df469) that will expand the page to include the Error Message if provided available from next v4.0.37+ release which is [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

You can remove the built-in 404 Handler in your ServiceStack AppHost with:

```
CustomErrorHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = null;
```

or add your own with:

```
CustomErrorHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] =
     new RazorHandler("/404");
```

Which will let you return a custom Razor page, e.g. `/404.cshtml`

Comment: I am running a self-host service.  Can I have a `RazorHandler` loading the content from resource?  And how could I access the error information within the cshtml page?

Comment: @user325320 There's a few API's, a quick shorthand is to use `base.RenderErrorIfAny()` or you can get the error model with `base.ModelError` or converted into a ResponseStatus with `base.GetErrorStatus()`